# Mutal TLS without revealing the accepted client certificate CAs in Java 11

Tags: java, ssl

We have a service where clients need to authenticate via mutal TLS with a client certificate. The idea is that our customers can register their own CAs for their clients.

According to [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4) the server may send a list of accepted CAs (which is currently the case):

> certificate_authorities
>
> A list of the distinguished names [X501] of acceptable
> certificate_authorities, represented in DER-encoded format.  These
> distinguished names may specify a desired distinguished name for a
> root CA or for a subordinate CA; thus, this message can be used to
> describe known roots as well as a desired authorization space.  If
> the certificate_authorities list is empty, then the client MAY
> send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType,
> unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary.

The issue is that we do not want do reveal all our customers by sending the CA list with every TLS handshake.

The question is, how to configure the Java `SSLEngine` so that it does not sent the DNs of the accepted CAs. We have currently set `SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true)`. What we have not tried out is setting setWantClientAuth(true) only, but this would make the client authentication optional. So the question is how to surpress that the SSLEngine to send the accepted Client CA DNs.

Comment: Is this a web service, where you want the user's web browser to send their client certificate?

Comment: Actually the application protocol is MQTT. But yes I want the client to send its client certificate.

Comment: which java version, tls version we're talking about here?

Comment: You can't. It woudl be a violation of RFC 2246 and successors. But you don't need your client CA certificates if they are ultimately signed by a public CA: you just need that CA certificate.

Comment: RFC 2246 describes TLS 1.0 which we deactivated as it is no longer considered as secure @user207421. So it still could be possible. Configuring a Public Root CA would allow any client using a certificate signed somehow over that public root CA to authenticate, which we (or our customers) dont want.